# Nodejs, bcrypt , Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bcrypt

I'm very new to Nodejs / Mongo (with Mongoose). I'm using the bcrypt module to hash the password from a HTML form. In my db.create function, I'm not able to store the variable storehash in mongodb.

I don't get any errors but its just blank in the database. I have crossed check every other line of the code and it seems to be working. I don't understand why I'm not able to store a variable as "password: storehash" whereas I'm allowed to store something like "password: 'test' "

I'm sure I'm making some noob mistake somewhere. I'd appreciate any help!

```js
var db = require('../models/users.js');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');


module.exports.createuser = function(req,res){

 var pass = req.body.password;
 var storehash;

 //passsord hashing
 bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err,salt){
  if (err){ 
   return console.log('error in hashing the password');
  } 
  bcrypt.hash(pass, salt, function(err,hash){
   if (err){
    return console.log('error in hashing #2');
   } else {

    console.log('hash of the password is ' + hash);
    console.log(pass);
    storehash = hash; 
    console.log(storehash);
   }
  });

 }); 

db.create({

   email: req.body.email,
   username: req.body.username,
   password: storehash,


}, function(err, User){
 if (err){ 
  console.log('error in creating user with authentication');
 } else {
  console.log('user created with authentication');
  console.log(User);
 }
}); //db.create


};// createuser function
```

Comment: code examples !

Comment: use the code formatter provided by SO dont post images of the code

Comment: haha i think i just did that. thanks!

Comment: welcome to SO ... always acknowledge correct answers to your questions by hitting the checkmark widget aside the answer ... this gives you points but more importantly it tells others the answer is valid - take care

Comment: sounds good! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `db.create` should go right below `console.log(storehash);`, not after the  `bcrypt.salt`.

When you put it after `bcrypt.salt`, what you do is: while you're generating salt for your password and then hashing the salted password, you're also storing stuff in your database using `db.create`. They are executed simultaneously, not sequentially. That's why, while you're hashing your password, you're also creating a user with `db.create` **without a password**.

In other words, it should be:

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err,salt){
    if (err){ 
        return console.log('error in hashing the password');
    } 
    bcrypt.hash(pass, salt, function(err,hash){
        if (err){
            return console.log('error in hashing #2');
        } else {

            console.log('hash of the password is ' + hash);
            console.log(pass);
            storehash = hash; 
            console.log(storehash);
            db.create({

                email: req.body.email,
                username: req.body.username,
                password: storehash,


            }, function(err, User){
                if (err){ 
                    console.log('error in creating user with authentication');
                } else {
                    console.log('user created with authentication');
                    console.log(User);
                }
            }); //db.create
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Oh yes! right. Got it. I believe I mixed up sync programming with nodes async nature. 

It's working now. Thanks a lot !!